# Reduce gap between subfloat and subcaption

Tags: spacing, subfloats

How can I reduce the gap between the subfloat and its caption? I tried to use

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{aboveskip=0pt}
```

but it doesnt work for me. Below is the snippet i have and the output

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{aboveskip=0pt}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Ground Truth]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-gt.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-rnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} \noindent\rule{14cm}{0.4pt}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-gt.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-rnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} \noindent\rule{14cm}{0.4pt}
        \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-gt.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-rnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} \noindent\rule{14cm}{0.4pt}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-gt.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-rnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:ms}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Try just using `skip=` (I don't recommend 0pt), and remove  the `\vspace`s.

Comment: i need the vspace to keep my large figure in 1 page

Comment: With `skip=0pt`+ `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`, there are chances the figures touch each other. Is there any reason why some rows might not go to the following page?

Comment: i need all the subplots to be in a page and if i do not use \vspace some of them dont show up in the page. I tried \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=-10pt} and some other numbers but i dont see any effect

Comment: any easier solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

instead of `\subfloat` environments from `subfig` package  i would rather use `tabular` and for rules use `\midrule` from `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\newcommand\insertimage[1]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=13mm]{#1}}
    \centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}c@{}}
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-1-gt.png}       \\
    Ground Truth                        \\
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-1-rnn.png}      \\
    Recurrent Neural Network            \\
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-1-vrnn.png}     \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-3-gt.png}       \\
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-3-rnn.png}      \\
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-3-vrnn.png}     \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-1-gt.png}       \\
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-1-rnn.png}      \\
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-1-vrnn.png}     \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-3-gt.png}       \\
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-3-rnn.png}      \\
\insertimage{ood-ms/ood-3-vrnn.png}
    \end{tabular*}
\caption{}
    \label{fig:ms}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your code squeezes my figures horizontally

Comment: @kong, sorry, i don't understand you. i haven't your figure, so i use `demo` option. size of figures are determined on the same way as you dona in your mwe.

Comment: sorry, i just had to remove height=13 for it to work correctly. thank you.