# reduce gap between subfigure and subcaption

Tags: subplot

I am trying to reduce the gap between the subfigure and the subcaption.

> \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty, aboveskip=10pt}

but the line of code above does not work.

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty, aboveskip=10pt}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Ground Truth]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-gt.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-rnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} \noindent\rule{14cm}{0.4pt}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-gt.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-rnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} \noindent\rule{14cm}{0.4pt}
        \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-gt.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-rnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-1-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} \noindent\rule{14cm}{0.4pt}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-gt.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-rnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ood-ms/ood-3-vrnn.png} }}
    \\ \vspace{-1\baselineskip}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:ood}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you post a full compilable document? A link to the graphic files, or at least their size?

Comment: What is the difference to your earlier question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407534/reduce-gap-between-subfloat-and-subcaption

Comment: @samcarter, this is the very same question. it seems that op is not satisfied with my answer :-(, so ask it again instead to try explain, what the answer should be improved.